# Bash - reverse order of curly bracket resolution

Tags: bash

Such code

```bsh
$ ls {a,b}{c,d}
```

runs `ls` command on following files: `ac`, `ad`, `bc`, `bd`.
Is there a simple way to reverse resolution order and generate such sequence: `ac`, `bc`,`ad`, `bd`?

**edit**
I want to run grep on particular subset of files inside a subset of directories like this:

```bsh
$ grep 'find this' {sub_dir_one,sub_dir_two}/some_loc/{file_one,file_two}
```

I want lines from both `file_one`, then both `file_two` with respect to `sub_dir_one` and `sub_dir_two` order.

I just wonder if there's some nice trick which prevents me from using loop.

Comment: Other than changing the brace expansion itself to `{a,b}c {a,b}d`?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes it's general exampl, I'm going to update question.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. You want the `grep` to visit the files in a particular order?

Comment: I remember distinctly that this was already asked, but I suck at searching. Anyways, `eval echo '{a,b}'{c,d}`

Comment: here it is: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525921/apply-brace-expansion-in-reverse-order

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, because I need output to be sorted in particular order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to bash man page, in the `Brace expansion` paragraph,

> The results of each expanded string are not sorted; **left to right order is preserved**.

So an alternative is to use a `for` loop:

```
for i in file_one file_two; do
   grep 'find this' {sub_dir_one,sub_dir_two}/some_loc/"$i"
done
```